# Can and should a duplicate be migrated?

Tags: discussion, support, duplicate-questions, migration

Suppose a question is declared a duplicate on one site.

- Can it still be migrated to other sites? [since I did not get my answer from other questions, my question was a duplicate of].
- Note: Also, the said question might not be a duplicate on the other site. So, is it a all right to migrate it?
- Please also can somebody guide me on how migration works?

Comment: These things can be case by case. Do you have a specific question you can link to?

Comment: If the duplicate doesn't answer your entire question, then the correct thing to do is to edit to clarify your question and explain how the duplicate doesn't address it, not just send it somewhere else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you didn't get an answer from the other question(s), your question has been duplicated to, edit your question to explain why it isn't a duplicate and why the other duplicates don't answer your question. That will put your question into the reopen queue where other users can consider that information and possibly reopen it.

As long as your question is on-topic on the site you asked it (and it probably is if it's a duplicate), editing is far the best way to proceed.

It's only worth migrating a question if you feel it's off-topic on the site it's currently on and both on-topic and high-quality on some other site. The on-topic part makes it hard for moderators to migrate as they may not necessarily be active on any other site and they are wary of migrating off-topic, poor quality questions.

It's usually simpler just to ask the question on the new site as long as it's on-topic on the new site. You should check the new site's help centre carefully before you post.

Answer (score 2):

I would say, very often, the answer is no.

The first course of action here might be to edit your question to *distinguish* it from existing answers - if the existing questions do not fit your needs, *show* you have seen them and *point out* how they don't work for you.

It's also worth considering that the point of duplicate migration *isn't* to rehome questions that a site does not want - it is to find places for *good* questions that happen to be off topic. In fact, personally I'd ask myself "should this question have been asked there in the *first place*?" when migrating. If it's a dupe, clearly it's on a site where it's on topic. If not, it's always better to ask on the site you know it'll not be closed on to start with. So... if you know it's a dupe on bananas.se, and know fruit.se has no question, ask on fruit.se, and *check* first.

And essentially that's what migration is supposed to be - a way to move *good* (and sometimes people forget this) off topic (and your examples fail here) questions to a site where they are on topic, for the benefit of anyone with the same problem.